# disorder in multiprocessing subprocess

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess

After running some compuations nicely in linear fashion with a moderator script (cf. below) calling an inner one performing the computation, I struggle
to bring it to execution when trying it with multiprocessing.  It seems that each CPU core is running through this list set (testRegister) and launches a computation even if an other core already performed this task earlier (in the same session).  How can I prevent this chaotic behaviour?  It is my first time attempting calling multiple processors by Python.

Correction:  The initial post did not show that the test is a string consisting calling "the inner script" with varying parameters m1 and m2 beside fixed arguments arg1 and arg2 belonging solely to this "inner script".

````py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess as sub
import sys
import multiprocessing
fileRegister = []
testRegister = []


def fileCollector():
    for file in os.listdir("."):
        if file.endswith(".xyz"):
            fileRegister.append(file)
    fileRegister.sort()
    return fileRegister


def testSetup():
    data = fileRegister
    while len(data) > 1:
        for entry in fileRegister[1:]:
            m0 = str(fileRegister[0])
            m1 = str(entry)
            test =  str("python foo.py ") + str(m1) + str(" ") + str(m2) +\
                    str(" --arg1 --arg2")  # formulate test condition
            testRegister.append(test)
            testRegister.sort()
        del data[0]
    return testRegister


def shortAnalysator():
    for entry in testRegister:
        print(str(entry))
        sub.call(entry, shell=True)
        del testRegister[0]


def polyAnalysator():
    # apparently each CPU core works as if the register were not shared
    # reference: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        jobs = []
        for i in range(3):   # safety marging to not consume all CPU
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=shortAnalysator)
            jobs.append(p)
            p.start()


fileCollector()
testSetup()
shortAnalysator()       # proceeding expectably on one CPU (slow)
# polyAnalysator()        # causing irritation
sys.exit()```
````

Comment: What is `str(python foo.py --arg1 --arg2)`? That doesn't look like legal Python.

Comment: @JohnAnderson You are right, and I corrected the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `polyAnalysator` is running the `shortAnalysator` three times. Try changing your `polyAnalysator` as follows, and add the `f` method. This uses the `multiprocessing Pool`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(test):
    sub.call(test, shell=True)


def polyAnalysator():
    # apparently each CPU core works as if the register were not shared
    # reference: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html
    with Pool(3) as p:
        p.map(f, testRegister)
```